# I can't access all of the software in Ubuntu 20.04.6

Tags: 20.04

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 and I'm finding that I can't access all of the software from applications.  I click the icon at the bottom of the tool bar and the first page of the applications come up but seems to judder.  But when I attempt to scroll down the list or click on the second little box on the right hand side nothing happens.  I don't suppose anybody would happen to know how I could solve this problem please as it is somewhat irritating.

Regards

Nick

Comment: Hello Nick can you provide screenshots

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more, e.g adding more screenshots, logs and etc.

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to respond.  I'm not sure how much a screenshot would help as every thing looks normal except it won't scroll down and I can't click on the second on the right to get to the second page of the applications.  But I will upload a screenshot for completions sake.  My other two laptops don't have this problem so I would guess it might be a hardware issue so I'm going to add a link to a file for the hardware list for the machine in question.  I'm not sure what logs might be relevant and you'd like to see.  But if you would advise me then I will add them

Comment: [link] (https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhM)

Comment: I was trying to add a comment but it seems to have vanished so having trouble.  Not sure how much a screenshot would be relevant or useful as all you see is a little vibration of the icons on the left and at the bottom of the applications but I can neither scroll down or click on the right but I was going to add a link to the screen shot but it doesn't seem to be working either and not sure how to upload an image.  I also thought it might be hardware so created a file of a hardware listing for the machine as my other two laptops run applications perfectly but having trouble with this as well

Comment: My comments don't seem to be appearing but they are there and at the moment the link isn't working.  Sorry for the difficulties I appear to be having

Comment: [link] (https://1drv.ms/t/s!AhM93NmnZ2RegZx8ksFDIw_HmY7K9w?e=u6xZH8)

Comment: The above is the link for the hardware and below will be the link for the screenshot.  I think I'm beginning to understand how this works.  Although it is irritating that every time I press the return key it puts my comment up.  So screenshot link below.  Can't see any other way of uploading it currently.  Hope that will do.

Comment: [link] (https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhM93NmnZ2RegZx9qdEqh3DymFR2VQ?e=lycYDH)

Comment: Sorry, just looked at the screenshot and it was rubbish.  Not quite sure why Ubuntu would take a screenshot and then add a massive picture of it's logo to the right of what I wanted.  Anyway, below is a link to the edited version of my screenshot.  Once more apologies for my lack of familiarity with the forum

Comment: [link] (https://1drv.ms/i/s!AhM93NmnZ2RegZx__dJnik6_G--hGQ?e=Y8cVyA)

Comment: I really do hope some of that helps, sigh

Comment: Wow, just learnt you might be able to insert an image with ctrl G.  Just going to try that.  Well that didn't seem to work, doh!!!  So how would I insert an image?